# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react datatable error

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, react-router

getting Error in map function.

```
 generateRows: function() {
    var cols = this.props.cols,  // [{key, label}]
        data = this.props.data;
```

Getting error in data (undefined value getting)

```
    return data.map(function(item) {

        // handle the column data within each row
        var cells = cols.map(function(colData) {
            // colData.key might be "firstName"
            return <td> {item[colData.key]} </td>;
        });
        return <tr key={item.BlogId}> {cells} </tr>;
    });
},
```

Comment: Where is this `return data.map`? Make sure `data` exists before trying to map it.

Comment: set your data in getInitialState method and then use it

Comment: How to set data in getInitialState . actually it sets after generateRows method called that's why curretly getting an error.

Comment: Here i am write the method to get the data:
var data;

var viewDBData= DBData.ViewBlog('',function (val, responseMessage) {
    data= JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(val).result);
});
and set the value of this.props.data to data = data

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting cols from props ,to make sure they exist at the initialRender you can add a check  and have the return in map in a single statement like

```
 return data && data.map(function(item) {

        // handle the column data within each row

        return <tr key={item.BlogId}> {cols && cols.map(function(colData, index) {
            // colData.key might be "firstName"
            return <td key={index}> {item[colData.key]} </td>;
        })} </tr>;
    });
```

Also provide a key for the elements returned from inner map function